# iOS- UICollectionViewCell asymmetric size of each cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

As per my understanding, collection view is collection of views having similar height and width of each cell.

Can i achieve below view with UICollectionview? Size to Fit content helps me to certain level but still how can i reduce/increase space between two cells in uicollectionview.

Can anyone just give pointers how i can achieve this with/without collectionview?

[image: Image Resource: Foresquare iOS app]

Comment: Yes, you can achieve with collection view and UICollectionViewFlowLayout. You have to play with custom collection flow layout

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using collection view of course.
Need to adjust cell size according to content.

Here is a good [example](https://github.com/remirobert/RRTagController)

Answer (score 0):

The method you want to look at is in the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout for example where tags in an array of tags strings

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: tags[indexPath.row])
        let size = CGSizeMake(attributedString.size().width, attributedString.size().height)
        return size
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm recognizing the screenshot you posted correctly the app you're trying to imitate is Foursquare. If that's the case, you may be interested in [FSQCollectionViewAlignedLayout](https://github.com/foursquare/FSQCollectionViewAlignedLayout), an open source project form Foursquare Labs which implements that very interface.